# Can AWS Private link be used within a same VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, vpc-endpoint, aws-private-link

I am currently using aws EKS where I need to expose services to an EC2 based nginx server.
My issue is I dont want to create any internet exposing service, So came across AWS Private Link.

Though my Ec2 and EKS are in same vpc, I only need AWs private link to be able to connect to the internal NLB, as when the request comes to nginx it is redirected to AWs Provate link to -> internal NLB.
Is this a valid use case for AWs private link, if yes how can I proceed further ?
Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/access-container-applications-privately-on-amazon-eks-using-aws-privatelink-and-a-network-load-balancer.html

I have tried creating an internal NLB, an endpoint service which is associated with NLB. Also created endpoint and connected with the link. How should I check the flow from endpoint.